# Save html of a Jupyter notebook from within the notebook

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

My Jupyter workflow for exploratory analysis looks like:

1. Fiddle with some parameters.
2. Run the notebook; generate output.
3. Eyeball outputs.
4. Repeat.

Can anyone suggest a command to make the notebook to save a copy of itself (e.g as an html in the output folder), so that if I want to recreate a particular experiment (results from a particular parameter set) I can do so?

Comment: `so that if I want to recreate a particular experiment I can do so?` - I don't understand that. Can you explain a bit why `File->Download as->html` does not work for you?

Comment: That works, but takes precious seconds, and requires me to remember to do so. I am asking if there is a way to recreate that process from within the notebook, so that it will happen automatically when i "run all"

Comment: ...and that places the the html in Downloads, which I then have to move... Just not efficient at all.

Comment: I guess your problem is not very common - usually converting the notebook to html only makes sense if you want to share it over the web. For looking at it locally or sharing the results other formats are much more convenient -  Anyways, you can try experimenting with savehooks. They could come very close what you are trying to achieve: http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending/savehooks.html

Comment: Thanks - the problem with save hooks (as I understand them) is that they can be used to save an .html copy in the same location as the .ipynb, but not in another specified folder. N.B. It doesn't have to be html - a .pdf or .py would work as well.

Comment: I have never used hooks, but from the post-save-hook example I do not see any restrictions where you can save to. The example uses `with io.open(script_fname, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:` It appears that you can open any file you have permissions to write to.

Comment: @DanielPower did you find a solution for this old problem? I am incurring in the same exact issues

Comment: @cel which formats are much more convenient?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Just add a safe cell by using cell magic. After using nbconvert you can rename the file and append a date

```
%%bash
jupyter nbconvert --to html MyNotebookName.ipynb
mv MyNotebookName.html $(date +"%m_%d_%Y-%H%M%S")_MyNotebookName.html
```

Comment: This doesn't work to save the current state of the notebook at the end of a run. The notebook does not auto-save during the run process, so a previous version of the notebook gets saved to html. Does anyone know how to programatically save the notebook within a cell so that the currently visible cell outputs get saved to html?